# Create a soaking portal in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I want to create a vortex/soaking portal in Unity by using a particle system.

Currently I use these settings for my particle system

[image: settings]

and I get this result

https://media.giphy.com/media/51W8tU4Cv9AapUfbr3/giphy.gif

What I want is a portal like the portal from Rick and Morty

[image: RickAndMorty]

or a simple vortex

[image: vortex]

How can I make the particle system soak into the center and go for particle lines like this (sorry for my bad painting skills)

[image: final]

Comment: You can use a gif as a texture for the main portal and then add the same particle effect as yours. This video may help.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VOi5BrEBW4

Comment: Or use *tons* more particles, larger particles, or multiple particle systems, possibly even including a change in color as the particles age. You might also want to enable Prewarm, too.